# Co-optimisation of Pyomo and EnergyPlus

Tags: optimization, pyomo, energyplus

I am trying to run pyomo optimisation while considering energyplus(eplus) temperature simulations as constraints of my objective function. It appears that eplus is called only once. How can I ensure that eplus values are updated during iterations?

## Below is the code;

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from EPlus.model import TemperatureModel
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

# Initialize the EnergyPlus model
EPLUS_model = TemperatureModel("C:\EnergyPlusV9-4-0")

# Create a Pyomo ConcreteModel
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# The time
model.time = pyo.Set(initialize=(range(30, 31 + 1, 30)))

# Optimised Variable
model.power_w = pyo.Var(model.time, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0, 40000), initialize=5000)

# Defining the expression for indoor temperatures
def ep_model(model, t):
    return EPLUS_model.T(np.zeros(96)+model.power_w[t])[0]
model.indoor_temps = pyo.Expression(model.time, rule=lambda model, t: ep_model(model, t))

# Adding temp limit as a constraint
def LB_rule(model, t):  
    return model.indoor_temps[t] >= 13
model.temp_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.time, rule=LB_rule)

# Define the objective to minimize total power consumption
def obj_rule(model):
    return sum(model.power_w[t] for t in model.time)

model.total_power = pyo.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=pyo.minimize)

solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
result = solver.solve(model, tee=False)

solved_p_values = {t: model.power_w[t].value for t in model.time}

solved_t_values = solved_t_values = [pyo.value(model.indoor_temps[t]) for t in model.time]#{t: model.indoor_temps[t]() for t in model.time}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't possible.  You cannot pass arbitrary external functions that depend on the value of a variable in pyomo and most other LP modeling packages.  The model is built *in entirety* and passed over to a solver, so the expressions in the model need to be defined in terms of model variables and constants upon construction

Comment: Thanks, but I have been suspecting that EXTERNAL GREY BOX MODEL (https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contributed_packages/pynumero/pynumero.interfaces.external_grey_box_model.html) can do the trick? Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know anything about that.  It seems contrary to the strengths of a LP package.  Anyhow, I believe there are other approaches to "grey box"  (aside:  didn't it used to be "black box"?) models.  `scipy.optimize.minimize` does such things and is well documented and has many examples on the site.  I would start SMALL with an easy model to get something basic working that you can do with pencil & paper or such then grow it.  I think using that can be tough to troubleshoot with all the options/opaque nature of the execution.